# How to use subdomains with different firebase hosting?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, dns, subdomain, firebase-hosting

I am using GoDaddy and Firebase. My domain [Main Domain](https://www.nextechmm.com) is hosted on one Firebase project. I am trying to use a [subdomain](https://www.lego.nextechmm.com)  on different firebase project. But when I reach this subdomain URL, it goes to [Main Domain](https://www.nextechmm.com) instead of [subdomain](https://www.lego.nextechmm.com). Is this the issue with Firebase or GoDaddy? How can I solve this issue?
I have been looking for this from past few days and couldn't resolve it.
Your help or suggestion will be a great help for me.

Comment: Right now there's *three* A record for the subdomain https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=lego.nextechmm.com&rtype=ANY, either you setup the record incorrectly (in GoDaddy) or if this is a recent change, it might haven't propagated to all server

Comment: ok, let me remove the first top one. It is not the one I added

Comment: The first one with (184.168.131.241) is not able to delete. No option in GoDaddy. is it can be from Godaddy Default?

Comment: Oh, yeah it's GoDaddy's IP. I tried the network tab on Chrome's dev tools, upon hitting the subdomain, your server *return* a 301 to the main domain.

Comment: https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422 Could be due to GoDaddy's configuration

Comment: Solved by removing subdomain name created in godaddy.